# How to install ftputil for Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, ftputil

I have been trying to install a module from this link https://github.com/camptocamp/connector-file/tree/master/connector_file. But when i am trying to install it, i am getting the following error :

Unable to install module "connector_file" because an external dependency is not met: No module named ftputil

I installed ftputil on the server, but the problem persists. Anyone kindly guide me on this.!! Thanks

Comment: refer this : http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/precise/universe/p/python-ftputil/install/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded ftputil from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftputil/2.2.3 and installed it and copied the folder to python folder in Odoo and renamed it to ftputil and restarted the server. Worked well!

Answer (score 1):

You can Download the High-level FTP client library named ftputil.[Download From Here.](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftputil/2.2.3)

Comment: I downloaded from there only!!